# Trouble burning CDs and DVDs in Windows

Tags: windows, dvd, burning, ahci, imgburn

I've run into some errors writing CDs and DVDs recently:

Trying to burn a dual layer disc using ImgBurn I come across this error when trying to finalize the disc.

```
Potential 'WaitImmediateIO' Deferred Error - (0%, 0/3) - Session Fixation Error Writing Lead In
Finalise Disc Failed! - Reason: Session Fixation Error Writing Lead In
```

[image: Error Message]

Anyone have an idea what could be the problem?  There is no problem until it comes time to finalize the disc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently SATA optical drives have a problem with being in AHCI mode.  To fix this issue I went into my BIOS and set my SATA drives to Standard IDE mode and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can find on [ImgBurn's forum](http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?showtopic=520), this issue is most likely caused by your dvd writer having difficulties to recognize the disc correctly. (Other forum post suggesting that, can be found [here](http://forums.afterdawn.com/thread_view.cfm/352367))

Try to upgrade the firmware from this dvd writer. If you need help with this, edit your question to precise which model it is, so we can help eventually with finding it.